# Can't install `eth-tester` Python Package

Tags: python-3.x, package, ethereum

I am trying to install `[eth-tester][1]` Python Package so that I can use it to load test ethereum in my account by using its `get_balance()` function.

First when i installed this package using;

> pip install eth_tester

It asked me to upgrade the `pip` version. I upgraded the pip. Now my pip version is 19.2.3. Now its giving me following error on installing the `eth-tester` package;

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mk141\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mk141\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mcki_ya9\\cytoolz\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mk141\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mcki_ya9\\cytoolz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mk141\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-viyzcfqs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\mk141\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mcki_ya9\cytoolz\
    Complete output (49 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils_test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mk141\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mk141\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mcki_ya9\\cytoolz\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mk141\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mcki_ya9\\cytoolz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mk141\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-viyzcfqs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I can easily install the other packages of python but i can't install this one. Is there any way to resolve this problem or is there any problem in this package? If there is any other way to load test ethereum in my account then please let me know.

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools`. Have you tried to resolve this error?

Comment: I just updated the version of `pip` and downloaded the package directly from `github` and tried to use that.

Comment: I think you should consider this error. Try to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.